# Storage Booster - Disable duplicate image scan

Tags: samsung, storage, 8.0-oreo, images

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5 with Android 8.0.0.

Occasionally I get a notification that Android found many duplicate images:
[image: Storage Booster notification]
It says: "Storage-Booster. Duplicate image found. There are 2549 duplicate images on your phone."

Most of them are images sent or received by messenger apps but sometimes it also detects similar images as duplicate, in rare cases even totally different images.

I don't want to delete any duplicated images for multiple reasons:

- I don't want to delete the original image, neither want the image in the messenger become unavailable
- I don't want to delete just similar or even totally different images
- They only occupy around 1 GB and I have plenty of free space on my SD card.

Is there a way to completely disable the duplicate image scan? I also expect it to draw a lot of energy when regularly comparing thousands of images in the background.

Comment: I don't know details on the image comparison in Samsung devices but commonly similarity is computer by a formula that assigns each picture In the media database one value. And "duplicates" are those that share the same number. That avoids comparing thousands of images and requires only a bit computation when the picture is taken or saved. Power usage for query the media database for finding similar images is neglectible. May be Samsung schedules those computations to be done while charging.